# VS Code terminal doesn't recognise Python interpreter or any command (complete beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm a complete beginner with VS Code and coding in general, and I'm trying to set up a Python environment to start learning. I have Python 3.8.1 installed, and it runs fine in my script, however I'm having problems running any command in the terminal: if I type in 'python' into the terminal window through my project path, it just opens up a prompt to install Python 3.7.0, and if I try to check 'pip list' or 'import sys', it just comes up as unrecognised. When I also try to create a virtual environment through 'python -m venv' + environment name, nothing happens.

I know it's something completely basic that I'm missing, but can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong that's preventing me from using the command terminal? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKpxq.png

Comment: OS? Platform? ? ?

Comment: Apologies, was in a bit of a rush - on Windows 10.

Comment: I would advice on Windows 10 to remove standalone Python and setup Anaconda (x64 3.7 default, 3.8 if you want via channel) - a lot of things just works. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/#

Comment: Alright thanks for the recommendation, will do!